# Is each tab in a browser single or multi-threaded?

Tags: multithreading, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge

I know that a each tab has its own process but is each tab also running in a single thread?

My assumption would be that the javascript has it's own thread and another thread for doing things such as http calls.

I'm doing a test to try and demo this by doing an http call with a lag time however I notice that when the http call actually happens I see no evidence of it in the devtools till I get a reply which would be consistent with single threaded unless it was designed that way.  Anyone have any insight into this?

Javascript

```
this.http.get(this.staffUrl)
         .toPromise()
         .then(response => response.json() as Staff[])
         .catch(this.handleError);
```

PHP

```
public function index()
{
    sleep(5);
    return response(DemoStaff::all(), 200);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Judging by network activity monitor, the main chrome process reads the network and sends the results back to each tab process.

Comment: @wOxxOm So is the main chrome process the thing that is doing the actual http request? So an http request would go tab process => main process => server => main process => tab?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.